# Habilitar botón con cualquier radio

Tags: javascript, html5

¿Cómo puedo habilitar un botón al dar <kbd>click</kbd> en cualquiera de los `radio button` de un mismo `name`. Aclaro que el número de `radio button` puede variar indefinidamente pero todos tienen el mismo `name`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>deferred.done demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <lavel class="theradius">
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    
    
  </lavel>
<button id="run" style="display:none">GO</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Te comparto un código para mostrar el botón cuando selecciones algún radio button.

```js
var opciones = document.getElementsByName('Nic');
for( var i=0,il = opciones.length; i< il; i ++ ){
 opciones[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}

function clickHandler(){
  var button = document.getElementById('run')
  button.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>deferred.done demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <lavel class="theradius">
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    
    
  </lavel>
<button id="run" style="display:none">GO</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Y si en vez de `radio` utiliza mejor un ***input*** tipo `checkbox`

La mayor diferencia es que el `radio button` te permite solamente elegir una solo vector u opción de la lista que te sale en el cuadro de dialogo, mientras que el `checkbox` te permite seleccionar varios y en algunos casos permite al usuario que pueda introducir un valor que el `radio button` no permite.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>deferred.done demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <lavel class="theradius">
    <input name="Nic" type="checkbox"/>
    <label># 1 Nic</label>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="checkbox"/>
    <label># 2 Nic</label>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="checkbox"/>
    <label># 3 Nic</label>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="checkbox"/>
    <label># 4 Nic</label>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="checkbox"/>
    <label># 5 Nic</label>
    
    
  </lavel>
<button id="run" style="display:none">GO</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

¡Espero sea de ayuda y sea lo que estás buscando, ya que la pregunta no es muy clara!

Comment: Si la pregunta no es clara, deberías pedir aclaración en la zona de comentarios... Desde mi punto de vista, tu respuesta no parece ser lo que busca el OP: 1- No estás habilitando el botón. 2- Que pasa si se necesita redireccionar a otra pagina de acuerdo a la opción seleccionada?. 3- Que pasa si quiere enviar la opción seleccionada a una base de datos?...

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no es muy clara la pregunta, me baso en lo que comentas: Que al dar click (cambiar) cualquiera de los radios se "active el Botón":

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>deferred.done demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <lavel class="theradius">
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    
    
  </lavel>
<button id="run" style="display:none">GO</button>
 <script>

$(function(){
$('input[type=radio][name=Nic]').change(function() {
$("#run").show();

});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tambien podrias hacerlo con un `disabled` para deshabilitar o habilitar el boton utilizando [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/), de la siguiente forma:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>deferred.done demo</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      
    </head>
    <body>
      <lavel class="theradius">
        <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
        <br/>
        <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
        <br/>
        <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
        <br/>
        <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
        <br/>
        <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
      </lavel>
    <button id="run" disabled>GO</button>
     
     <script>
        $('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){
            $('#run').attr("disabled", false);
        });
    </script>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yo e usado Jquery para cambiar el css del elemento y en vez de usar display e usado 'visibility' que viene a hacer lo que tu quieres.

**Es necesario que importes la librería de jquery para que te funcione.**

Si quieres ocultar el botón de nuevo tan solo tienes que cambiar de visible a hidden y listo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accion').click(function(){
    $('#run').css('visibility','visible');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>deferred.done demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <lavel class="theradius">
    <input class="accion" name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input class="accion" name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input class="accion" name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input class="accion" name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input class="accion" name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    
    
  </lavel>
<button id="run" style="visibility:hidden">GO</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No es necesario importar jQuery.

Comment: sino recuerdo mal sino se importa la libreria .min te dara el error de que no reconoce el caracter '$' de la línea 1

Comment: Me refiero a que no es necesario importar JQuery ya que la solucion se puede realizar sin necesidad de la libreria. Claramente si no se usa la libreria, no usaras $.

Comment: sisisi en eso tienes razón, esto se puede hacer de varias formas, eso no te lo discuto

Comment: Sólo lo comente por que el usuario no indico jquery, era solo una observacion

Answer (score 0):

Al button dale el mismo nombre  del grupo de radio buttons al que pertenece:

```
  <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
    <br/>
    <input name="Nic" type="radio"/>
  </lavel>
    <button  name="Nic"  id="run" disabled>GO</button>



  <script>

           $(function(){


                   $("body").on('click", 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
                            var name = $(this).attr("name");

                           $('button [name='+ name + ']').attr("disabled", false);
                });


             });
         </script>
```

El evento click lo haces al body para que no ataches un evento a cada radio button.